# <List filter= {....} > Or logic with List filters

Tags: typescript, react-admin, react-tsx

Ive tried both

```
 <List {...props}
      filter={filter1 || filter2}
      filters={<ListFilter />}
      bulkActionButtons={<BulkActions canEdit={canEdit} />}
      perPage={preferences.rowsPerPage}
      pagination={<Pagination />} >
           <ListDesktop canEdit={canEdit} />
 </List>
```

and

```
 <List {...props}
      filter={filter1 %% filter2}
      filters={<ListFilter />}
      bulkActionButtons={<BulkActions canEdit={canEdit} />}
      perPage={preferences.rowsPerPage}
      pagination={<Pagination />} >
           <ListDesktop canEdit={canEdit} />
 </List>
```

Its very difficult to find any documentation on the filter property. Is there a way to accomplish or logic in react admin?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without more context.

Anyway filter is a prop so I assume filter1 and filter2 are objects. Assuming that I think you have to join in one single object, e.g. :

when filter1={id:1} and filter2={id:2} then filter={{id:[1,2]}}.

Hope this solves it.

Comment: No I've tried that.

So lets say we have 4 field field1....field4,
I want to filter records based on field1 or field 2, in other words all records that have the criteria for field1 and all the records for field 2 without duplicates.

The equivalend sql would be SELECT * FROM  stormlight where field1 = kaladin OR field2 = myraize;

also is there any good documentation around the filter property?